# Error while developing my first android app with IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to learn android app development .I am using IntelliJ Idea 10.When I do what's told in 
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_Android_in_IntelliJ_IDEA
I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:70)
```

Please help me out of this.And please elaborate your answers as I am totally new to this

Comment: You're compiling the source files with a newer version of the Java compiler than the one you're trying to run the application with. Doublecheck that the SDK in the run configuration is the same one as in the project settings.

Comment: @Inerdial Please tell me how to do it.As I told before I am a beginer and totally raw

Comment: You should just use eclipse, its far more streamlined and WAY better looking.

Comment: @JoxTraex I know that.But still I have to use this because I dont have the eclipse IDE and my Internet speed is too low to download it right now.Furthermore that's not the solution to the problem.

Comment: Most developers use Eclipse when doing android development. Specifically this is a IntelliJ problem. its a problem with your "class version" whatever that means. Its saying you have a bad version number.. but it doens't say of what... so we dont have much information to go off of.

Comment: @user1020998 Then my metaanswer is "familiarise yourself with your chosen IDE". Then come back to my original answer.

Comment: @Inerdial You mean I have to use JDK 1.5 and not 1.7 for android development??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring Android SDK in IntelliJ IDEA you should set it to use JDK **1.6**, not 1.7. If you want to use 1.7 it looks like you need to [run IDEA itself under JDK 1.7](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/running-mustang/).

Comment: Do you have any idea,how to change the Idea_JDK variable??

Comment: Depends on your OS, try to Google how to set environment variables. But I'd recommend using 1.6 when developing for Android.

Comment: Start | Computer | Properties | Advanced System Settings | Environment Variables, or use some app like http://www.rapidee.com

Comment: I did it but nothing's happening.As you all told that android devlopment is better with eclipse IDE , I downloaded that and its working in that.But the problem in IntelliJ Idea is still not solved however.Please clarify it......

Comment: Create the new Android SDK in IDEA using JDK 1.6 instead of 1.7.